# "Matrix dimensions must agree " error in Scene change detection example in Matlab documentation

Tags: image, matlab, video, matrix, video-processing

I am using Matlab's [scene change detection example](http://www.mathworks.in/help/vision/examples/scene-change-detection.html) given on the Mathwork website. The code runs fine till the last leg where is is showing following error:

> Error using  -
>       Matrix dimensions must agree.
>       Error in scenechange (line 65)
>       edge_diff = abs(mean_blks - mean_blks_prev);

Line of error is:

```
edge_diff = abs(mean_blks - mean_blks_prev);
```

I checked the dimensions. They are: `15 1` and `70 1`. 
Anyone tried the example and got this error? How do I fix this error?

Comment: So you try to subtract a 70x1 vector from a 15x1 vector.  This is not possible as the vector do not have the same size. Make sure they are the same size.

Comment: You can subtract the first 15 elements of the second vector using 
edge_diff = abs(mean_blks - mean_blks_prev(1:15))

Comment: Can't I add zeros to make them vectors of same dims and then subtract?

Comment: I think NaN's would suit you better, as NaN - someValue = NaN

Comment: How would I add NaN's to my matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
len_mean_blks      = length(mean_blks);
len_mean_blks_prev = length(mean_blks_prev);

if len_mean_blks < len_mean_blks_prev
    padded_mean_blks                  = nan(len_mean_blks_prev, 1);
    padded_mean_blks(1:len_mean_blks) = mean_blks;
    edge_diff = abs(padded_mean_blks - mean_blks_prev);
elseif len_mean_blks > len_mean_blks_prev 
    padded_mean_blks_prev                       = nan(len_mean_blks, 1);
    padded_mean_blks_prev(1:len_mean_blks_prev) = mean_blks_prev;
    edge_diff = abs(mean_blks - padded_mean_blks_prev);
end
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, a typo: use nan (without the 's')

Comment: It means that the number of elements you want to assign in the vector does not match the number of elements in the source. In short, mean_blks_prev does have more elements than the value of len_mean_blks_prev.